# Object modeling Parent / Child Relationship for Java DTOs for JPA ORM

Tags: java, oop, jpa, orm

Based on the following requirements:

Have two endpoints, respecitively, which I am using Spring's RestTemplate client to consume and populate two separate DTOs. This part is done.

http://www.endpoint.com/Advertisement

Contains the following JSON array:

```
[{"startDate":"2017-01-29","cost":"$50000.00","id":1112,"name":"Porsche"},{"startDate":"2017-03-06","cost":"$27000.00","id":38626,"name":"BMW"}]
```

http://www.endpoint.com/Metric

Contains the following JSON array:

```
[{"clicks":1796,"views":13582,"id":20275,"parentId":1112},{"clicks":3295,"views":12697,"id":18564,"parentId":38626}]
```

Requirement 1:

The relationship between the two types of data are that of a parent and child relationship, Advertisement is the parent and the Metric is the child. The Metric contain metric data that can be used to describe the overall performance of the parent Advertisement item. Once the data is in the appropriate format, save it locally to a database of choice. Store the data in the database at the Advertisement level.

Requirement 2:

Write a method which performs a query on the database to retrieve all metrics for a given parent advertisement. Next, return an array containing only unique metrics, based on the metric ID, using only one array in code (i.e. in place removal of duplicates).

Requirement 3:

Write a database command/query (using your database of choice) to calculate total clicks and views at the Advertisement level per child metrics. Store these values alongside each advertisement object at the advertisement level.

So, basically, I started off the object design like this:

```
@Entity
public class AdvertisementDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String startDate;
    private String cost;
    private String name;

    // Getter & Setters
}

@Entity
public class MetricsDto extends AdvertisementDto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long parentId;

    private int clicks;

    private int views;

    // Getter & Setters
}
```

Question(s):

1. Is my ORM design regarding the parent / child relationship correct for requirement 1?
2. Am confused on if my Object design is applicable for Requirement # 2 & Requirement # 3?
3. How would i populate the appropriate parent id with the super class (AdvertisementDTO)?

Answer (score 1):

For me you do have two entities which stand in relation to each other. I also understand that one advertisement always has one metric and vice versa. If I'm right you can do it like that:

```
@Entity
public class Advertisement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="metrics_id")
    private Metrics metrics;

    private String startDate;
    private String cost;
    private String name;

    // Getter & Setters
}

@Entity
public class Metrics {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="advertisement")
    private Advertisement advertisement;

    private int clicks;

    private int views;

    // Getter & Setters
}
```

And for saving, deleting and finding you would need this in spring-data-style:

```
public interface AdvertisementRepository extends JpaRepository<Advertisement, Long> {

    List<Advertisement> findAll();

}

public interface MetricsRepository extends JpaRepository<Metrics, Long> {

    List<Metrics> findAll();
    List<Metrics> findAllByAdvertisementId(@Param("advertisementId") Long advertisementId);

}
```

To see how to arrange things best (in my opinion) look here: https://github.com/khauser/microservices4vaadin/tree/master/microservices/userservice/src/main/java/microservices4vaadin/userservice

To calculate a sum you would need to make something in that direction:

```
@Query("SELECT Coalesce(SUM(b.value),0) AS value "
     + "FROM Booking b INNER JOIN b.account a "
     + "WHERE a.itemId = :accountId "
     + " AND (b.bookingDate <= :toDate OR :toDate IS NULL)")
Double getAccountBalanceValue(@Param("accountId") Long accountId, @Param("toDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) LocalDate toDate);
```

Comment: KLHauser - thank you very much for taking an initial pass at this, I really appreciate it. How can I associate the parent id located in Metric with Advertisement? I don't see metric id specified anywhere (isn't it supposed to be just plain old "id")?

Comment: There is no patentId anymore. Access would bei through advertisement.getMetrics() or on the other site metrisch.getAdvertisement().